# Postfix cleanup logs not showing all mail ids in Cc header

Tags: postfix, email-server, log-files

**my main.cf file contains**

```
line_length_limit=4000
append_dot_mydomain = no

#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

compatibility_level = 2
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
smtpd_tls_security_level=none
smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
#KEEP DISABLED        check_policy_service { inet:127.0.0.1:10040, timeout=10s, default_action=DUNNO }
        permit_mynetworks
        permit_sasl_authenticated
        defer_unauth_destination

myhostname = test.test.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = localhost:1125
mynetworks = mx3.test.com mx4.test.com 172.31.0.0/16 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
split_address_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4

header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks

message_size_limit = 46080000
header_size_limit = 204800
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 2

content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
```

**these are the ids in Cc in my test mail**

```
`Cc:autumnleaf387@gmail.com, blazingfire459@gmail.com, curiousmind1234@gmail.com, dashingadventure789@gmail.com, enchanteddreams555@gmail.com, fearlesswarrior246@gmail.com, galaxyexplorer777@gmail.com, happygolucky123@gmail.com, inventivegenius234@gmail.com, joyfulspirit789@gmail.com, kindheartedsoul456@gmail.com, luminousmoonlight123@gmail.com`
```

**below is the postfix/cleanup log generated**

```
Jun 20 19:09:11 research-or1 postfix/cleanup[2127]: 8C208CFBD5: info: header Cc:autumnleaf387@gmail.com, blazingfire459@gmail.com, curiousmind1234@gmail.com, dashingadventure789@gmail.com, enchanteddreams555@gmail.com, fearlesswarrior246@gmail.com, galaxyexplorer777@gmail.com, from localhost[127.0.0.1]; from=<shahid@mithi.com> to=<shd@mithi.com> proto=SMTP
```

**The log is not showing all mail ids in the Cc header, some ids are missing in the logs, I'm facing the same issue in the To header also, if there is a bunch of recipients, how to fix this issue?**

***I have tried***

1. adding and increasing the line_length_limit
2. adding and increasing the header size limit

Comment: `header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks` — please post the contents of this file, **verbatim**

Answer (score 0):

Enable more verbose logging for Postfix by setting `debug_peer_list` and `debug_peer_level` parameters in main.cf